# How to copy and paste a range of cells from another worksheet depending on predefined indices in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to see why one can't do the following with respect to a block of a worksheet cell. (It works when I do a similar thing for other instances). Ultimately I'm trying to paste a formula (that calls a different sheet), across a range in my "Input" sheet.

The formula should read...

```
=+D14*(1+Sheet1!$D$4)
```

For the first cell, and it should change automatically for all other cells in the range.

Here is a simplified version of my code to get an idea as to what I've tried so far... Thanks:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteTest()
Dim ws(1) As Object

Set ws(1) = Worksheets("Input")

Dim idx_1, idx_2, idx_3 As Long 'no of cells

idx_1 = 76
idx_2 = 8
idx_3 = 3 + idx_2 + idx_1

ws(1).Range("D" & idx_3 & ":DR" & idx_2).Formula "=D14*(1+Sheet1!" & Chr(36) & "D" & Chr(36) & "4)"

End Sub
```

Comment: There's an `=` missing right after `Range("D" & idx_3 & ":DR" & idx_2).Formula`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Its been a long day! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No need for “assembling” your formula since it’s all made up of constants : = "=D14*(1+Sheet1!$D$4)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = Worksheets("Input")
```

And then:

```
Dim idx_1 As Long, idx_2 As Long, idx_3 As Long
```

And at the end:

```
ws.Range("D" & idx_3 & ":DR" & idx_2).Formula = "=D14*(1+Sheet1!" & Chr(36) & "D" & Chr(36) & "4)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I don't think there is any issue/need to change the first two lines?  (In my full code there are multiple worksheets ie ws(1),...,ws(10) ) Although the third point is correct, I left out an "=".

Comment: @SadMrFrown first you declare it as what it is so you can use the intellisence, otherwise you rely on vba to make the choice for you.  Second you need to declare each object separately like the suggestion, or the first two will be declared as variant and again you are relying on vba to decide what type it is to become.  This can lead to errors in the future.

Comment: @SadMrFrown also by using `WS(1)` you are declaring an array with 2 items `WS(0)` and `WS(1)`

Comment: @SadMrFrown If you do want an array of Worksheets, then declare it as such.  Also, be specific on the lower bound ie `Dim ws(1 to 10) as Worksheet`.  Vityata's second point is valid: your code declares `idx_1` and `idx_2` as `Variant`'s - probably not what you intended.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations guys. I am getting used to working in VBA again... I will be sure to implement the suggestions going forward!

Comment: @SadMrFrown - welcome back to VBA, it is really unlimited (whatever 99% of the people think about it). If you consider, that this answer has answered your query you may mark it as an accepted.